# Screenshot.jpg not visible in "recently used files"

Tags: gtk, gimp, screenshot

I created a screenshot with the default application of Ubuntu 20.04.

I save this to `Screenshot.jpg`.

I open Gimp and go to "Open / File". In the popup dialog I choose "recently used files".

But `Screenshot.jpg` is not in the list.

How can I make my screenshots available in the file dialog recently file list?

Comment: In my system (also 20.04) it **does** appear in the *Recent* section.

Answer (score 1):

"Recently used" files are listed in a `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` file (which is normally shared by all apps).

If you use the Gimp flatpak version, this version has its own copy of `~/.local/share/` (in `~/.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/data`) so has its own copy of the `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` file, so has its own list of recently used files.

You can't replace `~/.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/data/recently-used.xbel` by  a link to `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` because this file is erased/recreated by Gimp (and the re-creation doesn't re-create the link). But you can replace `~/.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/data/` by a soft link to `~/.local/share/` and Gimp will happily share the file with others.

I don't know is this applies to other installation modes (snap, for instance) but this is fairly easy to try.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. In this case I am just a user. I want it to work. I don't want to create symlinks

Comment: You would be creating links between two directories in your user space. I have been running like this for over a year on one of my PCs.

Comment: great that you are able to create symlinks. Thousands of Ubuntu users are not able to do this. How could we find a solution which works for all out of the box?

Comment: If you want to file a bug against the packaging this is not the place to ask. I'm just providing a solution to make it work with what you have. Note that you can likely create a link with you file explorer: if you drag/drop a file/directory in your explorer, you can choose between move, copy, or link.